# JS как посчитать значения столбцов в таблице?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Например, имеется такая таблица, в которую поочередно добавляются строки, как можно посчитать и занести в итоговую строку, сколько всего Футболистов, Пловцов и Баскетболистов добавлено?

```js
function deleteRow() {
  tg.deleteRow(1);
  if (document.all("tg").rows.length == 2) {
    document.getElementById("b").disabled = true;
  }
}

function addRow() {
  var f1 = document.getElementById("f1").value;
  var f1k = parseInt(f1);
  if (isNaN(f1k)) {
    f1k = 0;
  }

  var f2 = document.getElementById("f2").value;
  var f2k = parseInt(f2);
  if (isNaN(f2k)) {
    f2k = 0;
  }

  var f3 = document.getElementById("f3").value;
  var f3k = parseInt(f3);
  if (isNaN(f3k)) {
    f3k = 0;
  }
  var sum1 = (f1k + f2k + f3k);
  var row = document.createElement("TR")

  var tbody = document.getElementById("tg").insertRow(1);

  var r1 = tbody.insertCell(0);
  r1.innerHTML = "";

  var r2 = tbody.insertCell(1);
  r2.innerHTML = f1;

  var r3 = tbody.insertCell(2);
  r3.innerHTML = f2;

  var r4 = tbody.insertCell(3);
  r4.innerHTML = f3;

  var r4 = tbody.insertCell(4);
  r4.innerHTML = sum1;

  if (document.all("tg").rows.length >= 3) {
    document.getElementById("b").disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```css
#tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

#tg td {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
}

#tg th {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
}

#tg .tg-yw4l {
  vertical-align: top
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <label for="n">Футболистов: </label>
  <input type="text" id="f1" />
</div>
<div class="row">
  <label for="n">Плавцов: </label>
  <input type="text" id="f2" />
</div>
<div class="row">
  <label for="n">Баскетболистов:</label>
  <input type="text" id="f3" />
  <button id="a" onClick="addRow();return false;">Добавить</button>
  <button id="b" onClick="deleteRow();return false;">Удалить</button>
</div>
<table id="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-031e"></th>
    <th class="tg-031e">Футболистов</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">Плавцов</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Баскетболистов</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Всего</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Итого</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function deleteRow() {
  tg.deleteRow(1);
  if (document.all("tg").rows.length == 2) {
    document.getElementById("b").disabled = true;
  }
  
  // вызываем ф-цию при каждом нажатии на Добавить или Удалить
  countSum();
}

function addRow() {
  var f1 = document.getElementById("f1").value;
  var f1k = parseInt(f1);
  if (isNaN(f1k)) {
    f1k = 0;
  }

  var f2 = document.getElementById("f2").value;
  var f2k = parseInt(f2);
  if (isNaN(f2k)) {
    f2k = 0;
  }

  var f3 = document.getElementById("f3").value;
  var f3k = parseInt(f3);
  if (isNaN(f3k)) {
    f3k = 0;
  }
  var sum1 = (f1k + f2k + f3k);
  //var row = document.createElement("TR")

  var tbody = document.getElementById("tg").insertRow(1);

  var r1 = tbody.insertCell(0);
  r1.innerHTML = "";

  var r2 = tbody.insertCell(1);
  r2.innerHTML = f1;
  r2.classList.add('football'); // добавляем вставляемым ячейкам классы (1)

  var r3 = tbody.insertCell(2);
  r3.innerHTML = f2;
  r3.classList.add('swimming'); // (2)

  var r4 = tbody.insertCell(3);
  r4.innerHTML = f3;
  r4.classList.add('basketball'); // (3)

  var r4 = tbody.insertCell(4);
  r4.innerHTML = sum1;

  if (document.all("tg").rows.length >= 3) {
    document.getElementById("b").disabled = false;
  }
  
  countSum();
}

function countSum() {
  var cs = [0, 0, 0]; // массив для сумм ячеек
  
  // пройдемся по каждому ряду таблицы
  
  Array.from(document.getElementById("tg").rows).forEach(function(item) {
    if(item.querySelector('.football')) {  // просуммируем значения ячеек с подходящими классами
      cs[0]+= +item.querySelector('.football').innerHTML;
    }
    
    if(item.querySelector('.swimming')) {
      cs[1]+= +item.querySelector('.swimming').innerHTML;
    }
    
    if(item.querySelector('.basketball')) {
      cs[2]+= +item.querySelector('.basketball').innerHTML;
    }
    
    // присваиваем получившиеся суммы
    document.getElementById("football-sum").innerHTML = cs[0];
    document.getElementById("basket-sum").innerHTML = cs[2];
    document.getElementById("swim-sum").innerHTML = cs[1];
  });
  
  // ищем и присваиваем получившуюся сумму для ячейки "Всего"
  document.getElementById("global-sum").innerHTML = cs.reduce(function(sum, current) {
    return sum + current;
  }, 0);
}
```

```css
#tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

#tg td {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
}

#tg th {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
}

#tg .tg-yw4l {
  vertical-align: top
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <label for="n">Футболистов: </label>
  <input type="text" id="f1" />
</div>
<div class="row">
  <label for="n">Плавцов: </label>
  <input type="text" id="f2" />
</div>
<div class="row">
  <label for="n">Баскетболистов:</label>
  <input type="text" id="f3" />
  <button id="a" onClick="addRow();return false;">Добавить</button>
  <button id="b" onClick="deleteRow();return false;">Удалить</button>
</div>
<table id="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-031e"></th>
    <th class="tg-031e">Футболистов</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">Плавцов</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Баскетболистов</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Всего</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">Итого</td>
    <td class="tg-031e" id=football-sum></td> <!-- добавил для каждой ячейки суммы id -->
    <td class="tg-031e" id=swim-sum></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l" id=basket-sum></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l" id=global-sum></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```